# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

so i installed the MySQL application for the first time. firstly i saw the command line client is not opening so i searched for solutions. they said i must go to the bin directory and run it manually. and after i run the cmd `mysql -uroot -p` and run it and enter password, it gives me the error: *ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'* **i tried every single solution on stackoverflow including disabling permissions, running manually which i mentioned above, starting the service from service.msc, running it with password and without.... it just doesnt want to work.**
appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer myself. Seemingly, if you get this error, it means that you need to reset your password. You can learn [how to do that in MySQL from this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html).

And don't forget to change the 5.7 version with your currently installed version in using commands (mine was 8.0).
After that, everything was working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

### GENERIC MYSQL INFO

To start with, read the mysql manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

The steps will show you how to shut down the service and start it with an overriding command that doesn't require passwords, then you reset the password. From the manual:

Stop the MySQL server, then restart it with the `--skip-grant-tables` option. This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges and disables account-management statements such as `ALTER USER` and `SET PASSWORD`. Because this is insecure, you might want to use `--skip-grant-tables` in conjunction with `--skip-networking` to prevent remote clients from connecting.

Connect to the MySQL server using the mysql client; no password is necessary because the server was started with `--skip-grant-tables`:

```
shell> mysql
```

In the mysql client, tell the server to reload the grant tables so that account-management statements work:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then change the `'root'@'localhost'` account password. Replace the password with the password that you want to use. To change the password for a root account with a different hostname part, modify the instructions to use that hostname.

MySQL 5.7.6 and later:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

Or directly on the user table:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD('mynewpassword') WHERE user='root';
```

### XAMPP SPECIFIC

Stop the MySQL service. Open a **command window**. Change to the XAMPP MySQL directory:

```
> cd \xampp\mysql\bin\
```

Run the service without security (note you are running mysqld, not mysql):

```
> mysqld.exe --skip-grant-tables
```

The MySQL service will be running in this window, so open another command window and switch to the XAMPP MySQL directory:

```
> cd \xampp\mysql\bin\
```

Run the MySQL client:

```
> mysql
```

Update the password:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD('mynewpassword') WHERE user='root';
```

Exit MySQL:

```
mysql> \q
```

Use task manager to cancel the mysqld.exe that is still running. Restart the mysql service.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and I fixed it by running 'mysql -u root -p -f'

It then prompted me for a password. Not sure if that is force or not, but it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).